# Integer and string Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, forms, variables, addeventlistener

i do a simple exercise *"Write a JavaScript program to compute the sum of the two given integers. If the two values are same, then returns triple their sum"*. 
InnerHTML is ok but it seems that my variables are string and not numbers (if i use parseFloat however it doesn't work).
Example : p161 = 10; p162 = 5; => ris = 105 and not 15

```
let p16 = document.getElementById("p16");

document.getElementById("button16").addEventListener("click", es);

function es(){

    let p161 = document.getElementById("input161").value;
    let p162 = document.getElementById("input162").value;

    let ris = 0;

        if (p161 == p162){
            ris = (p161 + p162)*3;
            return p16.innerHTML = ris;
        } else {
            ris = p161 + p162;
            return p16.innerHTML = ris;
        }

}
```

Comment: Just change `p161` & `p162` using parseFloat and it will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are concatenating strings so what you see makes sense. Since you are looking for the sum of *integers* I dont see why you need to parseFloat. If you want numbers you should just do

```
let p161 = +document.getElementById("input161").value;
let p162 = +document.getElementById("input162").value;
```

Plus sign in this case is the unary operator that will convert value to Number type according to [ECMA](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6) spec